# GA event tracking in Buttons in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How to write below code as a method in Vue.js

`onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, { eventCategory: ‘Recommendations‘, eventAction: ‘View’, eventLabel: ‘Home Page Recommendation’, eventValue: 0});”`

Answer (score 0):

```
<button @click="callGa">GA Call</button>

methods: {
   callGa() {
       ga(‘send’, ‘event’, { eventCategory: ‘Recommendations‘, eventAction: ‘View’, eventLabel: ‘Home Page Recommendation’, eventValue: 0});
   }
}
```

ga should be imported or included to window or somehow else provided inside component

Comment: Acutally I have one existing submit handler already.
<button @click="submit()">GA Call</button>
And If I am trying to merge callGa() into submit() .Then this method is not working.

Comment: Can we add multiple handlers ?